# How to convert all inline style css with dynamic class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to capture all inline css and append it to style tag with unique class name.

i.e. from

```
<div style="top: 250px; left: 250px;" class="search">
```

to

```
<div class="search custom-class1">
```

Where `custom-class` will be created dynamically in css style tag.

Is there any way of doing this with `jQuery`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why, Can't you just use the same classnames?

Comment: see [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: What if you have color:black; in one style attribute and color:blue; in another ? like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="a" class="a" style=".."></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>

..

var inlineStyle = $('#a').attr('style');
$('.a').attr('style', inlineStyle);
```

if i undertand the task, the solution will be this

Answer (score 0):

Although there would be many other ways to handle your situation. But If you really want to do like this. try this code, however its working but if you want any enhance you can easily go further.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="color:black;">
        <div style="color:blue;">abc</div>
        <div>Xyz</div>
        1111
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
allstyle = "";
classNames = "";
count = 1;
$("*").each(function() {
  tag = $(this);
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    if(this.name == 'style'){
        allstyle += this.value;
        tag.removeAttr("style");
        tag.addClass("custom-class"+count);
        classNames +=" .custom-class"+count+"{"+allstyle+"}";
        count++;
    }
  });
});

$("<style>").html(classNames).appendTo("head");
</script>
```